# ImportError: No module named requests while running spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, python-requests, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to use a python package named "requests" along with a program using pyspark. I have downloaded the required package and am able to work with it for a normal python program by including 'import requests', but it does not work with pyspark program and shows  "ImportError: No module named requests".

## code

```
def get_text(s):
    import requests
    url = s
    data = requests.get(url).text
    return data
```

## calling function

```
newrdd=newrdd.map(get_text)
```

## output error line

```
16/12/12 15:42:33 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 48, node090.cm.cluster): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/local/hadoop-2/tmp/hadoop-yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/wdps1615/appcache/application_1480500761259_0178/container_1480500761259_0178_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in     main
    process()
  File "/local/hadoop-2/tmp/hadoop-yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/wdps1615/appcache/application_1480500761259_0178/container_1480500761259_0178_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 167, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/local/hadoop-2/tmp/hadoop-yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/wdps1615/appcache/application_1480500761259_0178/container_1480500761259_0178_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 133, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/var/scratch/wdps1615/spark-2.0.2-bin-without-hadoop/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1507, in func
  File "/var/scratch/wdps1615/Entitytext.py", line 45, in get_text
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

[Link to error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27IvF.jpg)

Comment: Can you run `pip freeze` in the same folder that contains your script?

Comment: Yes, 'requests==2.12.3' is there in the list.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and this worked for me:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages')
import requests
```

you can use `python2.7` instead of `python3.5` as well but you have to make sure that the pip package is installed and available in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have executed your pyspark application **on another python** interpreter, ensure that you have installed `requests` package for that interpreter, you can check whether `requests`installed in `[PYSPARK_VENV]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` folder.

Running command and restarting your application shall fix problem :

```
/var/scratch/wdps1615/spark-2.0.2-bin-without-hadoop/pip install requests
```